# If $B$ is the closed unit ball of $X$, Why does $\varphi (B)$ is $\sigma $-dense in the closed unit ball of ${X^{**}}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\varphi $ be the embedding of $X$ into ${X^{**}}$  . Let $\tau $ be the weak 
topology of $X$, and let $\sigma $ be the $weak^*$-topology of ${X^{**}}$--the one induced by $X^*$.

- If $B$ is the closed unit ball of $X$, Why does $\varphi (B)$ is $\sigma $-dense in the closed unit ball 
  of ${X^{**}}$?

Comment: Google "Goldstine's Theorem".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208389/proof-of-goldstines-theorem